# How to dynamically change configuration of a running Xserver?

Tags: display, screen, configuration, xserver

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3 on Intel's HD4000 GPU.

While Xserver is running, I would like to:

- add a new dummy screen to a running xserver (existing session, no DM involved)
- set resolution of display inside newly created screen
- set the position of that screen to be right-of existing screen